# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute - FileInputStream

Tags: java, android

this is my path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20180626_221051.mp4
```

but when I put this url to `FileInputStream` I got this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20180626_221051.mp4

my code is:

```
    String _path = path;
    URI uri = URI.create(_path);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(uri)); // error line
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

where is my wrong?

Answer (score 1):

either pass the path directly in the file constructor without wrapping in a URI or else prefix the path with a protocol, `file:` in this case.

```
file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20180626_221051.mp4
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20180626_221051.mp4
```

Comment: plz write an example.

Comment: this is my final code and I got the same error: `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MP4_20180626_221051.mp4")); 
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);`

Comment: did you get IllegalArgumentException or FileNotFoundException?